# External hard drive has no UUID

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hard drive from this kit meant for a pi zero. The hard drive has a cord coming off it that has a USB and two ways of powering on through a USB hub from the kit on the zero and then one for direct power from an outlet. Right now I've got it directly powered and the pi seems to find the hard drive when I do `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` but shows no UUID for it. How do I get the UUID for it?

Comment: Could you show us the full output of that command?  The hard drive might need to be partitioned and formatted first.  To get the UUID, you can also use the blkid command.

Comment: It's actually *partition*, or more accurately filesystem, UUIDs that count for most purposes; for how to set them see here: http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-change-the-uuid-of-a-linux-partition/

Comment: *"How do I get the UUID for it?"* -> To clarify, these things are not serial numbers, i.e., they are not hard-wired anywhere and can be set and changed arbitrarily with software; generally random values are used.  The point of using the UUID format is that it is incredibly unlikely that you end up with the same two used for anything.

Comment: @JohnHawthorne I tried blkid and my hard drive doesn't show on that list. Output of `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODE` https://pastebin.com/rcFfRF8p (has to use pastebin as it is too long)
Here is the output of blkid https://pastebin.com/saD1nZpH

Comment: as the first couple of comments suggested, the UUID output by lsblk is a filesystem UUID - clearly, from your output, the hard drive has no partitions and therefore no filesystems on it

Comment: @JaromandaX How do I add a file system and what type should I use?

Comment: parted  or fdisk to create a partition. mkfs to make a filesystem.

Comment: @JaromandaX what type of partition should I use for reading and writing?

Comment: @QuintinVanBooven - what filesystem are you going to use? the choice of "partition type" should be based on the filesystem you plan to use, e.g. if you intend on creating a ext4 filesystem, you'll want a Linux partition, most likely `83` - if you want FAT32, you'll want to use W95 FAT32 LBA partition `0c` - with parted, you use mkpart with a FS-TYPE - it will set the appropriate partition ID for you ... so, if you `mkpart primary ext4 ...` it will set the partition ID to a linux type `83` most likely

Comment: @JaromandaX I already made the filesystem and it auto made it ext2. I should mentioning I plan on using it just for storage

Comment: ok, so, if the HDD *now* has an ext2 filesystem in a partition, `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` should show that partition, and the UUID of the filesystem